# What does this statement mean in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, cmp

When tackling to translate the following segment of code, can someone tell me the purpose of `ptr` being there?

```
cmp byte ptr [eax], 0
```

ptr is a label, it has the value:

```
(++>
```

My understanding with `cmp` is that it compares the value on the left, with the value on the right.

With the third parameter involved (`ptr`), what does this mean? Is it comparing `ptr` AND the memory address value in `eax` with `0`?

If someone could translate it into English for me, that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Intel assembler syntax, there is no explicit mention of the operand size. When you say `mov eax, 0`, it's clear that a 32-bit operand is needed (since `eax` is 32 bit wide), and `mov al, 0` implies 8 bits.

But when you dereference a memory location, there is no way to infer the operand size, so you have to specify it explicitly by saying `byte ptr`, `word ptr`, `dword ptr` or `quad ptr`, for 8, 16, 32 and 64 bit operands, respectively.

So your instruction is comparing one byte (8 bits) at the memory addressed by the value of `eax` with 0.

Comment: For 10-byte extended precision floating point values, it's either `tword` or `tbyte`; syntax varies. Because it's not technically ten words, it's ten bytes.

Answer (score 0):

`eax` contains a pointer to some address. The instruction cmopares the byte value `eax` is pointint to with 0.

Similar to:

```
char *p = addr;
if(*p == 0)
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

PTR is not an instruction operand, but rather an option of the first operand.